# Проблемы с миграцией rake db:create_migration NAME=create_products

Tags: база-данных, ruby, миграция

**Текст ошибки в Terminal Ubuntu 18.04**

```
rake db:create_migration NAME=create_products --trace
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base
/home/alex/ruby/projects/PizzaShop/app.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/home/alex/ruby/projects/PizzaShop/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

**app.rb**

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record/version'

set :database, "sqlite3:pizzashop.db"

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
get '/' do
    erb :index
end
get '/about' do
    erb :about
end
```

**Rakefile:**

```
require "./app"
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
```

Comment: Вы используете гем `sinatra-activerecord`? В app.rb надо реквирить `require "sinatra/activerecord"`. Если у вас модульно приложение, то надо зарегистрировать `register Sinatra::ActiveRecordExtension`

Comment: @Василиса, реквирить от слова queer?

Comment: @Nakilon а как вы считаете более правильным транслитерировать это слово? :)

Comment: @Василиса, Спасибо! зареквирить помогло!

Comment: @Sasha с вашего позволения сконвертирую свой комментарий в ответ, чтобы  вопрос не висел неотвеченным

Comment: @Василиса на этом сайте и так слишком много ненужных попыток русскими буквами писать английские слова. "В app.rb надо делать require "sinatra/activerecord"" Ну или как вы в ответе написали, да.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `require "sinatra/activerecord"` в `app.rb`, без этого класс `ActiveRecord::Base` будет недоступен